# Simple fixes for improving multi-user MS Access performance?

Tags: networking, microsoft-access, query

I'm overhauling the entire IT infrastructure for a small office. They had a Dell T410 doing nothing but serving as a Win2k8 file share, so I figured I could replicate its functionality on an unused desktop running Vista while I took the server down for a rebuild.

That's all fine and good, but one thing they were doing was simultaneously accessing an Access database off of the share. It worked, slowly, while on the T410 but once I migrated it to the temporary server only one user can use it at a time-- additional users drag it to an unusable halt. There are 30-60 second pauses for queries. Everything else runs well enough.

This was something my predecessor had to deal with, and the office ladies are saying he had done *something* on the server to lessen the query time to 5-10 seconds.  They instantaneously run in single-user mode, but there is no documentation of what he did to mitigate this for multiple users. The server had no RAMDISK, RAID setup or anything special from what I could tell.

First I thought the hard drive might be slow so I set up a RAMDISK and am hosting that one particular file on it. Single-user access is now blazing fast but multi-user access is still just as slow. Next I thought the network card might be a bottleneck but I've watched the resource monitor and nothing is anywhere near capping out. My next thought was to blame hardware/Vista but it's a Dell somethingorother Core 2 Duo with 3GB of RAM, and Vista Business is the only OS I have a spare license for. Should be enough for the job at hand.

I've seen a lot of similar complains about poorly-designed Access databases being unusable in multi-user environments, followed by suggestions to split the database into front-ends and back-ends but I'm not willing to spend much time tweaking Access considering my next project after rebuilding the server is redesigning the entire back-end in SQL Server. Plus, the last guy was able to semi-fix the problem without overhauling anything (this much I do know). In the meantime though, this is killing productivity.

What might have changed between the old server and the new? Are there any simple things I can change to bring the query time back down to a reasonable delay?

Comment: Windows' Desktop OS's don't allow as many simultaneous connections as a Server OS, how many users are trying to use it at once?

Comment: Most of the day, 2 users at a time. There are rare occasions where there are up to 4. 

Forgot to mention, the entire network is wired, and the temporary server is hooked up directly to the 10/100 switch, same as the old server. Thanks

Comment: Are they all just loading the same DB into Access and editing it directly, or is it a Frontend/backend setup?  If it's FE/BE, Is there any reference in the Frontend's code to the BE server?  If so, is it still accurate now that you moved it to a new path?

Comment: No FE/BE; it's just a monolithic .mdb database. I knew going into this that they were going to have performance/scalability issues with their current setup, hence my push for a proper redesign. They used to open it via the G: drive, which I have since remapped on all the workstations to the respective location on the temporary server. The database *works*, just not in a productive manner.

Comment: This is exactly what splitting will solve. It will be faster and more stable. Splitting is no more complicated than running a wizard in Access and distributing the front end to all your users desktops (making sure it points to the right backend file)

Answer (score 1):

Splitting into fe,be is not complicated. Then link tables from be. These are deployment basics for ms access.  If you are facing msql build then splitting a database will be very easy.